# Disk names in Solaris 10 for ZFS: SAS WWN instead of c0t0d0

Tags: solaris, zfs, sas, nexenta, illumos

I currently have a server running Solaris 10u9 with a SAS enclosure (Dell PowerVault MD1000) filled with SATA disks attached to an SAS card (LSI 3801E).  It happily recognizes the 15 disks in the MD1000 and presents them each disk in the traditional solaris form (c1t12d0, c1t13d0, c1t15d0, etc).  My home ZFS setup (Nexenta CP3 + LSI 9200-16E + directly cabled SATA disks) presents disks as their SAS WWN ID (ex: c3t600039300001EA56d0).  Although this ID is longer, I've found it much easier to troubleshoot because the cabling/slot is irrelevant, ZFS just identifies the disk by ID, if it's connected it finds it.  Most manufacturers print the WWN right on the disk's top label, can't get much easier than that.

So how can I get Solaris to identify disks by [SAS WWN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name) instead of by the cXtXdX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be that you had to enable mpxio to get that type of notation. You may want to try enabling it and seeing what happens.

http://nilesh-joshi.blogspot.com/2009/08/sun-solaris-mpxio.html

Comment: You got it.  `pfexec stmsboot -e` is all it took.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a controller-specific thing. The newer LSI controllers use the WWN format for disk identification. You don't have any options to do this on other controllers.

Comment: I thought this might be the case.  Any one know if the older controller can be coaxed into using the WWN for disk identification?

Comment: You probably won't be able to. Try `cfgadm -vla` though. That *may* show a little more info about the drives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Only SAS and Fibre Channel devices have WWNs. These are assigned to a device by the manufacturer. As you have SATA drives in your enclosure there are no WWNs available for Solaris to read.

Comment: Not true, my Western Digital RE2 (160GB, 1TB), RE4 (2TB) and Hitachi UltraStar (1TB) all of which are SATA have WWN printed on the label.

Comment: @notpeter: But do they have the same in firmware to be read by the controller ?

Comment: @notpeter:  I think it's slightly more comlicated than that - have a look at [section 3.1 of this document](http://arc.opensolaris.org/caselog/FWARC/2008/013/commitment2.materials/sas-bindings.txt) which will clarify the situation. The WWN is generated by the STP/SATA bridge ...